# String.format() value in statusstrip label displayed differently on Win 7 vs Win XP

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp, string-formatting

I am using the following code to display the elapsed time of a task in the status bar in my application.

```
public void DisplayDuration(TimeSpan duration)
{
    string formattedDuration;

    if (duration.TotalMilliseconds < 2000)
        formattedDuration = string.Format("{0} ms", duration.TotalMilliseconds);
    else if (duration.TotalSeconds < 60)
        formattedDuration = string.Format("{0} sec", duration.TotalSeconds);
    else
        formattedDuration = string.Format("{0} min", duration.TotalMinutes);

    this.TimingLabel.Text = formattedDuration;
}
```

this.TimingLabel is a label in the statusStrip control in the footer of the winform.

But I get completely different results on Windows XP vs Windows 7

Windows XP:
[image: elapsed Time formatted XP]

Windows 7
[image: elapsed Time formatted 7]

Why is the units appearing before the time in Windows 7?

I have checked Regional Settings both machines are set to US with same Date Time formatting. Make quite quite sure it is the same code running on both machines.
This is very odd behavior in some very simple code.

As a follow up: I made the following change to my code but still have the same problem:

```
formattedDuration = string.Format("{0} ms", duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the same code is running on both operating systems?

Comment: What do the additional settings for "Numbers" set for "No. of digits after decimal" for each system?

Comment: Im going to go out on a limb here and guess that you're not showing us all the code involved in assigning text to `TimingLabel`.

Comment: What version of .NET are you on?  Is it possible that you've compiled for 3.5 and one machine has .NET 4 and the other one doesn't?  Try forcing a runtime with your app config file.

Comment: Absolutely Yes!  It was the first thing I checked. The Windows XP image is taken from development machine and the Windows 7 image taken from a test mahcine where I installed the application.

Comment: The application is a .NET 3.5 app but .NET 4.0 has been installed in my Windows 7 test machine.

Comment: Try replacing "string.Format("{0} ms", duration.TotalMilliseconds);" with "string.Format("{0}", "Foo");" Do you get "Foo" as the output? If yes, try replacing that with "string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} ms", duration.TotalMilliseconds);" Same result?

Comment: For reference, in 0.0004 ms a beam of light will travel 392 feet. How much precision do you need?

Comment: As FishBasketGordo said, it probably isn't the same code on both systems.  In Windows XP, the 'ms' comes after the number, and in Windows 7 it comes before.

Comment: It is the same code.  VSS 2008 solution file in XP and installed application on Windows 7.  Double, double checked it.

Comment: This is all of the code used to set the label Timinglabel.  The width of the label is set to be dynamic not fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the most likely probably here is a layout issue and not `String.Format`.  Regional settings shouldn't be a factor here because you're not asking the `TimeSpan` to format its value.  Instead you're asking `String` to format a string "ms" followed by a number.  It would be simply a bug if it inverted them in the output.

What's much more likely is that the number is being clipped via a bug in the layout constraints of the container.  If I look very hard at the screen shot there does appear to be a divider immediately to the left of the `ms` string.

Try giving everything a fixed width which is fairly large and see if the correct display comes back.

Comment: It is a layout error.  When I make the labels fixed width, value is formatted correctly.

Comment: @Gary: Wouldn't it be good to edit the title of your question then?

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer was the label in the status had its RightToLeft incorrectly set to true. This property was not respected by Windows XP but is used Windows 7+.